# Pair records by grouping on foreign key

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

I am stuck on a question I got in a coding challenge. Essentially I have 3 tables; ratings, reviewers, and books.

The ratings contain a list of book reviews from reviewers. I need to output a query that shows pairs of reviewers that reviewed the same book.

Please see [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c5363d) sqlfiddle to get the schema.

The desired output is:

```
"Name 1"     |  "Name 2"
Joe Martinez | John Smith
```

This is the desired output because in the ratings table reviewer_id 15201 and 44203 both reviewed book_id 101 and their names are Joe Martinez (reviewers.id = 15201) and John Smith (reviewers.id = 44203)

The only other requirements were to not have duplicate pairs. It didn't say anything regarding if there are multiple pairs for a single book. I would think if book_id 101 had 4 pairs then it would display 2 rows (4 names in total).

Comment: a coding challenge is by definition a challenge, and your challenge. As a hint you'll need to join to reviewers `twice` with a different table alias. Keep playing, try things, and show an attempt (or multiple).

Comment: @danblack I was ready to dive in, until I read your sage words. I've upvoted your comment (doesn't mean anything though, does it?). Nice one!

Comment: ... and each `reviewers` table copy must be joined to its own `ratings` table copy.